# Adding an event handler to any Controls causes error in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, mfc

I have a MFC Application with a single exe loading multiple dll's, in one of my dll project's I have a dialog being created and I'd like to add an event listener for when a checkbox is changed. When I use the resource editor to add an event handler it adds a definition to my header file, a function in my cpp file and it adds a line between the

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CHardwareListing, CDialog)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()
```

portion of the code, but this line that its adding,

```
ON_BN_CLICKED(IDC_CHECK1, &CHardwareListing::OnBnClickedCheck1)
```

causes a strange error that I dont know how to interpret.

> "Error, expected an expression"

The reason I find this error is strange is because I have other files that were set up the same way without this error, in fact that look almost identical to this after adding the event handler. Any help on what causes this and how to fix it?

Comment: Total shot in the dark...is there anything else between the BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP and END_MESSAGE_MAP?  Assuming there is, that error could be produced by the code just above it.  There must be a reason Visual Studio is expecting an expression from that line so I would look hard at the code just above it and possible try to move the offending line to a new location.  On a side note...Using Visual Studio 2012 and working with MFC applications firmly anchors you in the old timer hall of fame.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Pointers:

- Ensure the class has `DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP` in header
- Ensure that base/derived classes in `BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP` are correct
- Ensure that `CHardwareListing::OnBnClickedCheck1` does exist and is of correct type. Also check that `IDC_CHECK1` is valid.
- Ensure that `resource.h` is included in CPP or in header.

Also, please ignore this warning/error if it was reported by Intellisense, and not by actual C++ compiler

Answer (score 0):

I found the fix to this error, for some reason Visual Studio placed a "&" character before the "CHardwareListing" argument which was causing the problem. Still not sure why that character was inserted in the first place.

Comment: It is fairly standard these days for the class wizard to add the & character prefix.